# need to make curve line using css

Tags: css

I am trying to create curve line  like this using css:

[image]

this to make it curve, but not able to do.or is it possible to make one border solid line to make it curve like this? 
Thanks in Advance.. any one can help me out

My code: http://codepen.io/elad2412/pen/PwWjLL

```
.box{
  width:500px; height:100px;  
  border:solid 5px #000;
  border-color:#000 transparent transparent transparent;
  border-radius: 50%/100px 100px 0 0;
}
```

Comment: i am using this http://codepen.io/elad2412/pen/PwWjLL as reference, but can able to make it curve.

Comment: What is this? Sine wave or 2 semi circles?

Comment: add reference link on your question

Comment: why don't you use SVG?

Comment: i add one reference codepen, i was trying out, got codepen from reference question. its not two circles. its a border line i need to make it curve, is that possible??

Comment: no i can not use svg, path, i need by css, is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```css
.wave {
  width: 800px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.wave:after {
    content: '';
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    height: 200px;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 19px solid black;
    border-radius: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}

.wave:before {
    content: '';
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    height: 200px;
    display: block;
    border-top: 19px solid black;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wave">
  
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EWpjpx