# How can I curve background CSS with transparency?

Tags: html, css

I want to do this:

[image]

In the above photo, there's a gold strip border and a blue gradient background. And the name of the item is dynamic, meaning some names are short, some names are long.

Do you have any idea how can I do this using HTML and CSS?

I already saw this question: [need to make curve line using css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43014832/need-to-make-curve-line-using-css)

But that question doesn't answer my problem.

Comment: @Amit, I already saw that but that doesn't resolve my issue. That question is only doing a center curve. What I want to do based on my screenshot is the double curly curve.

Comment: Why you want it to be CSS, HTML. SVG is good for this use case.